# SelectNodes в HtmlNodeCollection (HTMLAgilityPack)

Tags: c#, xpath, htmlagilitypack

Добрый день!
Изучаю парсеры.
Столкнулся с проблемой, что при:

```
HtmlNodeCollection ticketNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*
[@class='ticket']");
HtmlNodeCollection numbersNodes = null;
numbersNodes = ticketNodes[0].SelectNodes("//*[@class='numbers']");
```

в numbersNodes выбираются все значения, подходящие под заданное условие, из всей коллекции ticketNodes, в количестве 36 штук. Хотя, если к примеру выводить на экран ticketNodes[0], то выводится только 6 numbers, как и должно быть.
Так и должно быть?
В итоге мне нужен массив numbersNodes[6]. Но из-за того, что выбираются полностью все значения, то в каждом элементе массива находится одно и тоже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вроде вы получаете то, что заказывали.

XPath `//*[@class='numbers']` означает поиск всех элементов с нужным значением атрибута во **всём** документе, начиная с корня. (Вот примеры того, что означают различные XPath-выражения: [XPath Examples@MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Вероятно, вы хотели написать `.//*[@class='numbers']`?